# Add horizontal scroll bar to a bucket list in R

Tags: r, shiny

So I am working on a project in which I am using a bucket list within a shiny app. What seems to happen is when I add to many ranked lists to my bucket list, rather than the horizontally scrolling over to the next ranked list, the list appears at the very bottom of the page instead. Here is a brief example of what I am working with:

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(sortable)

ui<- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "test app"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Bucket Test", tabName = "bucket")
        )
    ), dashboardBody(
        sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                     h2("Menu Options")
        ),
        
        tabItems(
            tabItem(tabName = "bucket",
                    style = "overflow-x: scroll",
                    bucket_list(
                        header = "Choose a bucket",
                        group_name = "bucket_list_group",
                        orientation = "horizontal",
                        add_rank_list(text = "Bucket 1",
                                      labels = c("hi", "this", "is", "a", "test"), 
                                      input_id = "1"),
                        add_rank_list(text = "Bucket 2",
                                      labels = NULL,
                                      input_id = "2"),
                        add_rank_list(text = "Bucket 3",
                                      labels = NULL,
                                      input_id = "3"),
                        add_rank_list(text = "Bucket 4",
                                      labels = NULL, 
                                      input_id = "4"),
                        add_rank_list(text = "Bucket 5",
                                      labels = NULL,
                                      input_id = "5"),
                        add_rank_list(text = "Bucket 6",
                                      labels = NULL,
                                      input_id = "6")
                    )
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there a way to allow for a horizontal scroll bar to scroll through these buckets rather than having them appear at the bottom of the page? As you can see, I did attempt to add a scroll bar, but for whatever reason it doesn't change the results(the scroll bar is there, just blank). Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `dashboardPage` is not a function inside the `shiny` package...

Comment: Whoops sorry. Forgot to add the other libraries.